# How to add an item to the Google Drive "New..." menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How can I add an application to the Google Drive "New..." menu?

I've built a little script, but I don't know how to make it appear in that menu like other apps.

[image: screenshot]

I want this option so that my script can ask some questions before creating a document for the user.

Comment: [The documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en) is clear about what Web UI extensions can be made with Google Apps Script; _you can extend the capabilities of documents, spreadsheets, and forms by adding custom menus, dialogs, and sidebars_. You appear to be asking about extending the Google Drive web UI, which isn't supported.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I'm wondering how my application can appear when we click on the red "create" button on the left side of gdrive. I can see other apps but not mine. So, it's possible, but I don't find how to do.

Comment: I understood your question, although it was not clear - that functionality is not provided by Google Apps Script, and isn't under your programmatic control. If you publish an app in the Google Apps Marketplace, you have the option to have your app [configured as a Drive extension](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing#about_app_extensions); if the app is accepted, that configuration results in the app appearing as a "create" option _once installed_.

Comment: Ok this is my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Great - I've updated your question to clarify it, and put that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is not provided by Google Apps Script, and isn't under your programmatic control.

If you publish an app in the Google Apps Marketplace, you have the option to have your app [configured as a Drive extension](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing#about_app_extensions); if the app is accepted, that configuration results in the app appearing as a "New / More" option once installed.